# Upload image to firebase from hybrid app

Tags: javascript, mobile, firebase

how can I upload an image from his path "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D6326867-A474-481F-B6B4-5A9A6251CC0E/tmp/cdv_photo_013.jpg" to firebase storage using Javascript ? Cause I know how to using Blob or File but not from a single path...

Answer (score 0):

Here my resolved code :

```
uploadPicutre(uri:string, userUid: string){
    let self = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      function toDataUrl(url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.onload = function() {
          callback(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.send();
      }

      toDataUrl(uri, blob => {
         self.refStoragePicture.child(userUid)
          .put(blob).then(snapshot => {

            self.refStoragePicture.child(userUid)
              .getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
                resolve(url);
              }).catch(function(error) {
                reject(error);
              });

          }).catch( err => {
            reject(err);
          });
      }) 
    })
  }
```